# node Tedious sql (mssql) после первого успешного запроса, бд не дает соединиться

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

Есть скрипт на node, Tedious driver, mssql 2014. Windows server.

Первый запрос на соединение успешен, выполняется 6 запросов в базу, все в порядке все успешно.

Второй запрос с теми же конфигурациями подключения выдает ошибку - ETIMEOUT - не могу подключится к базе данных в течении 15 секунд.
при этом предыдущий запрос точно выполнился и соединение точно закрылось.

В журнале событий пустота по этому поводу, но
Есть запись - в кольцевом буфере   - security error ring buffer recorded, error code 5023.

Пробовал как просто запросы так и пулы ( пулы выдают уже 3 успешных подключения а иногда и 1 , после чего такая же ошибка )

При этом на другом компьютере такой же скрипт выполняется без каких либо ошибок хоть 100 хоть 200 раз одновременно.

Возможно что, что-то из окружения влияет на соединение, возможно какие то тонкие настройки соединения, но сама база на тестовой машине ( на которой все работает )  такая же.

В общем буду рад любой гипотезе, возможно ошибка в чем-то банальном.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает что "**Группа или ресурс находятся в неправильном состоянии для выполнения запрошенной операции**"

Посмотрите в журналах просмотра событий и ошибок SQL Server. Есть ли неудачные логины? Вы также можете посмотреть в трассировке SQL Server по умолчанию для событий неудачного входа в систему, используйте этот запрос

Кольцевые буферы предлагают большое количество информации. Чтобы запросить RING BUFFER SECURITY ERROR, используйте этот запрос:

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar(30), GETDATE(), 121) as [RunTime],
dateadd (ms, rbf.[timestamp] – tme.ms_ticks, GETDATE()) as [Notification_Time],
cast(record as xml).value('(//SPID)[1]', 'bigint') as SPID,
cast(record as xml).value('(//ErrorCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)') as Error_Code,
cast(record as xml).value('(//CallingAPIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') as [CallingAPIName],
cast(record as xml).value('(//APIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') as [APIName],
cast(record as xml).value('(//Record/@id)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Id],
cast(record as xml).value('(//Record/@type)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [Type],
cast(record as xml).value('(//Record/@time)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Time],
tme.ms_ticks as [Current Time]
from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers rbf
cross join sys.dm_os_sys_info tme
where rbf.ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_SECURITY_ERROR'
ORDER BY rbf.timestamp ASC
```

После того как вы определили код ошибки, используйте SPID для отслеживания ошибок с помощью Profiler, трассировки по умолчанию или других пользовательских сценариев SQL

Ресурс: https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2015/05/troubleshoot-sql-security-error-ring-buffer-recorded-system-health-.html

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но к сожалению тот ресурс уже проштудировал, использовал profiler выбрал там мониторить почти все и успешные запросы генерировали 80 записей, а не успешный - ничего, никакой реакции. Получается   что в кольцевом буфере запись есть, а profiler не видит. подскажите что мониторить в profiler что бы увидеть ошибку - error code 5023